# When deserializing JSON into my Java Classes with Generics (with Jackson) I run into a stackoverflow due to recursion. How do I solve this?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm using Jackson to deserialize JSON into Java.
I have the following classes (showing only snippets):

```java
public class NavMenu {
    private final List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Menu implements ItemContainer<Menu> {
    private final List<Item<Menu>> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Item<P extends ItemContainer<P>> implements ItemContainer<Item<P>> {
    private final List<Item<Item<P>>> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

public interface ItemContainer<T extends ItemContainer<T>> {

    void add(Item<T> item);

    List<Item<T>> getItems();
}
```

It appears that when deserializing the `Menu` there's a recursion resulting in an eventual StackOverflow error. The stacktrace looks as follows:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBase.toCanonical(TypeBase.java:72)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType.buildCanonicalName(SimpleType.java:236)
    ...
```

I actually solved it by writing my own `NavMenu` deserializer but it's recursive and fairly hard to understand, so I was wondering if this is a bug in Jackson or if there are annotations / ways to circumvvent having to write my own Deserializer.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing is not a bug in Jackson, but rather a limitation in its handling of recursive data structures. Jackson's default behavior for deserialization is to use reflection and recursively traverse the object graph, which can lead to a stack overflow error when dealing with deeply nested structures.

Jackson allows you to register modules that can modify its default behavior. You can create a custom module and override the default handling of certain types. This approach provides more flexibility and allows you to encapsulate the custom deserialization logic

example -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NavMenuDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<NavMenu> {

    public NavMenuDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public NavMenuDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public NavMenu deserialize(JsonNode node, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        NavMenu navMenu = new NavMenu();
        JsonNode menusNode = node.get("menus");
        if (menusNode != null) {
            for (JsonNode menuNode : menusNode) {
                Menu menu = context.readValue(menuNode.traverse(), Menu.class);
                navMenu.add(menu);
            }
        }
        return navMenu;
   }
}
```

To use the custom deserializer, you can register it with an ObjectMapper instance like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(NavMenu.class, new NavMenuDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        // Now you can use objectMapper to deserialize your JSON
        NavMenu navMenu = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, NavMenu.class);
    }
}
```

By providing a custom deserializer, you have more control over the deserialization process and can handle recursion and complex object relationships as needed

Comment: The OP specifically stated that they already have a custom deserializer, and ask about alternatives.